# How can i find an app that needs parallelized systems

Tags: parallel-processing, system

I have an assignment for school to make an existing app using parallel systems. Can someone give me an idea of what should I write about?

Answer (score 1):

An easy option, if you are new to parallel systems, would be to choose something that is *"trivially parallelisable"* or *"embarrasingly parallelisable"* where nothing is dependent on anything else. Try Googling those terms.

Examples might be:

- ping 200 IP addresses in parallel - hint use **GNU Parallel**
- resize 100,000 images to 50% of their original width and height - hint: use **ImageMagick** and **GNU Parallel**
- grab 100 webpages in parallel